# Why are extra 50 bounty "from the system" not added anymore?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

Previously when bounty was offered the site added 50 extra points (say the user offered 150 points and the site added 50 to that, so 200 points were awarded). Now those extra +50 are no longer offered.

Why exactly was this changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

> The system no longer tosses in +50
> bonus reputation to a bounty. We feel
> this newer, much more open bounty
> system no longer needs that incentive.

Comment: Didn't notice that in the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The bounty system was improved in a number of ways last month; the [blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/) about it has a bullet about the extra 50 rep:

> The system no longer tosses in +50 bonus reputation to a bounty. We feel this newer, much more open bounty system no longer needs that incentive.

Comment: beaten by 6 seconds! :)

Comment: @Jeff The other answer only had the link when I answered too; I saw it and thought "he's going to edit it to have the same quote, and I'm going to be sad inside". Ah well