# What's the purpose of "You can accept an answer in N seconds" hint?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Recently I asked [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56993/why-are-extra-50-bounty-from-the-system-not-added-anymore) that was answered pretty quickly (in several minutes). Since the two answers were good, I tried to upvote both and accept one of them. When I clicked "accept" I saw a hint "You can accept an answer in 57 seconds". Each time I clicked on "accept" I saw the same hint with lower value.

What is that hint about? Which moment is the time counted from? Why have I never seen that hint before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait 15 minutes after the question is first asked before you can accept an answer on it. It's to give people a chance to comment on the early answers and post their own, so you don't immediately accept the first answer. See [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste) and [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste/44099#44099)

Comment: I see. I guess it is also to encourage hitting "refresh" to see the newly added answers. The more I use the trilogy sites software the more I'm fascinated with the amount of polish on different aspects of user experience.