# "You can accept an answer in 0 seconds" looks weird

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer, timestamps

Turns out every user [needs to wait](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56996/whats-the-purpose-of-you-can-accept-an-answer-in-n-seconds-hint) 15 minutes between asking a question and accepting an answer on it. If he tries to click "accept" earlier he sees "You can accept an answer in N seconds" which is good... except that I recently tried to accept an answer earlier than after 15 minutes, didn't know about the 15 minutes restriction and clicked again and again until finally I saw "You can accept an answer in 0 seconds".

Now the latter text looks really weird. I guess the system compares the time elapsed as some fraction of seconds but the user interface code normalizes that value to be a whole number of seconds. So I hit an edge case where the comparison code thought that it's "greater than" but the user interface showed a hint related to "is equal".

Could you please fix this edge case? I guess the easiest solution would be to treat `0 <= N < 1` case as `N == 1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0 seconds` is perfectly good English. It's only `1 seconds` that's [inappropriate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times).

Comment: It's not the English that's the problem.. If you can accept in 0 seconds.. why, that's right now! So just let the user accept it!

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Is your browser not rendering the humor fields?

Comment: Oh, I guess not. Damn.

Comment: @Blorgbeard 0.4 seconds are only 0 seconds by virtue of rounding.

Answer (score -3):

> clicked again and again until finally I saw "You can accept an answer in 0 seconds".

For some reason when you said that I was thinking of this.

[image]
<sub>(source: [exotica.org.uk](http://www.exotica.org.uk/mediawiki/files/thumb/d/d1/Track_and_Field_title_(arcade).png/300px-Track_and_Field_title_(arcade).png))</sub>

We now show "you can accept an answer just now" -- for past or future dates <= 4 seconds.

Considering changing that to "momentarily" for future dates... let me make that so.

Comment: I guess that picture is of something that is very familiar to you but totally unfamiliar to me and this is why I don't get your perfectly crafted irony. Anyway I don't see why fixing the described behavior is that problematic.

Comment: Should be a comment.

Comment: But comments can't have images. Did somebody say "feature request"?

Comment: +i: I'm curious, but I don't understand.

Comment: @Pekka: I disagree...a link would easily do.

Comment: Ended up asking about it at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22808/ : basically it's talking about button-mashing.

Comment: I remember playing that arcade. What a nice memory. `:-)`