# "You can accept an answer in 0 seconds."

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“You can accept an answer in 0 seconds” looks weird](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56998/you-can-accept-an-answer-in-0-seconds-looks-weird)

Uh... Jeff, is this an off-by-one error? Or is it due to some effect of General Relativity I'm not familiar with?

Comment: @YOU: The *question* is a dupe all right, but the answers there don't answer the question.

Comment: Yeah, That's why I upvoted this post, but possible duplicate vote is different case. You posted this to get some attentions right?

Comment: `"You can accept an answer in" +  Math.Floor((DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds);`

Comment: I think they just need to change operator ">" to ">="

Comment: @Mehrdad I think Jeff's answer to the other question answers this as `status-dontcare-wontfix`. :)

Comment: @YOU: Not sure what you mean by "get some attention"... I certainly posted it to get attention to the bug, yes, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Pekka: ...yeah good point. That was July, you think anything's changed since then? (Wishful thinking I know...)

Comment: @Mehrdad, I think "get some attention" I meant is probably explained in ["How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: @Mehrdad I doubt it. But then, it's not really *that* big of a bug, is it? Seeing as it doesn't limit usability at all.

Comment: @Pekka: Well okay, but the off-by-one *is* a bit uh, weird, considering that this is a programming Q/A site...

Comment: @YOU: Interesting link, thanks for posting it.

Comment: @Mehrdad: It may not be an off-by-one thing. I'll bet it's a display issue - you actually have to wait 0.34 seconds, rounded down.

Comment: @Michael: Yeah that was my guess too -- I didn't mean off-by-one as in the code, but off-by-one as to what the user sees.

Comment: probably, off-by-one was my wrong assuming above, I didn't realized that .TotalSeconds is `double` :P

Comment: @YOU, *change operator ">" to ">="* — might be true, or maybe the code that renders the message calculates the remaining time itself again, using the slightly later current time?

Comment: @Arjan, the changes I meant to '>=' was something like `if now - posted_time -15.minutes >= 0: accept_done else: response_error_msg` I was assuming that smallest unit was seconds in interger :P

Comment: Wow, Jeff... way to answer the question. -__-